# Simple.Data Sqlite Insert returns Null

Tags: sqlite, return-value, simple.data

Im using Simple.Data to insert data into an Sqlite database. I read on the wiki that Insert returns the inserted data. I need to get the latest rowID (identity). But I get Null instead.

Using the Stable version from NuGet.

```
var db = Database.OpenFile("Database.db");
var x = db.Scan.Insert(Name:"Test", Description:"test", CreationDate:DateTime.Now, DocumentDate:DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate:DateTime.Now);
```

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Scan ( 
    ID           INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY,
    Name         NVARCHAR( 50 )  NOT NULL,
    Description  TEXT,
    CreationDate DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    DocumentDate DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    ModifiedDate DATETIME        NOT NULL 
);
```

Does this even work for SQLite? If not whats the best way to retrieve the rowID of the inserted record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same "issue".
The problem lies within your schema.

You have to add identity to your primary key column:

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
```

Then you get back the row and you can i.e. create a new object with it:

```
var x = db.Scan.Insert(Name:"Test", Description:"test", CreationDate:DateTime.Now, DocumentDate:DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate:DateTime.Now);
return new Scan { ID = (int)x.ID, Name = x.Name, ... }
```

From the Wiki:

> If you have an IDENTITY column defined on your table, then the Insert
>   methods will all return a copy of the record fetched from the
>   database, so all defaulted values are set. In 0.4, support for other
>   ways of fetching the inserted row will be added.